# Unable to accessible some code in TypeScript TS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, typescript

I have a simple if else code in TypeScript.But in some code unable to access it.It shows me the following error,

> "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNewsProvider')"

### Code

```
 if (this.newsShow != null) {
        if (this.glbNews.nIds == null) { 
            this.setNewsProvider(); //Accessible Here
        }
        else {
            if (this.newsShow.EmpLst == null) { 
                this.setNewsProvider(); // Accessible Here
            }
            else {

                if (this.newsShow.LCL == "X300") {
                    if (this.newsShow.MXD == "N300") {

                        var prd1 = this.newsShow.ProducerChk;

                        this.glbNews.PrdNcc.forEach(function (value) {
                            if (value == prd1) {
                                this.setNewsProvider(); //Un accessible here.. "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNewsProvider')"
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                       //Some code here
                        })
                    }
                }
              

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `forEach` loop you enter a function, the function has it's own this value. To avoid the problem, JS programmers used to often write

```
const that = this;
```

at the entry point and then use `that.setNewsProvider()` so that a more locally scoped this does not override it.
if you use an arrow function the problem will be avoided as these do not have their own local this value.

```
this.glbNews.PrdNcc.forEach((value) => {
  if (value == prd1) {
    this.setNewsProvider(); 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You used a regular function `function() {}` instead of an arrow function, which is `() => {}`. Regular functions don't capture the `this` keyword, but arrow functions do.

Because `this` isn't captured, you get the `Cannot read properties of undefined` error because the `this` inside of the `function(value)` is a different `this` than the one outside. Any properties and functions of `this` would not be brought into the regular function.

The fix is to use an arrow function, ie.

```js
...
this.glbNews.PrdNcc.forEach((value) => {
  ...
});
...
```

Here's a post that more thoroughly explains the differences between the two function types:

[Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)